# How to get completion for wrapping functions?

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I have a PowerShell function that wraps a call to three other functions, as follows:

```bsh
function Do-Thing {
    Foo
    Bar @Args
    Baz
}
```

Any argument passed to `Do-Thing` will be forwarded to `Bar`. The `Bar` function has a `param` block defined:

```bsh
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter(Position = 0)]
    [ValidateSet('Debug', 'Release')]
    [string] $BuildType = 'Debug'
)
```

The problem I'm facing is that I get tab-completion when trying to call `Bar` directly but not when trying to call `Do-Thing`. PowerShell seems to be unable to see through what I'm trying to do.

Is there any way I can get tab-completion for `Do-Thing` as if I'm trying to call `Bar` without duplicating the `param` block inside of `Do-Thing`?

Answer (score 0):

Simply declare the same `param` block in the outer function and splat `$PSBoundParameters` instead of `$Args`:

```bsh
function Do-Thing {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Position = 0)]
        [ValidateSet('Debug', 'Release')]
        [string] $BuildType = 'Debug'
    )
    
    Foo
    Bar @PSBoundParameters
    Baz
}
```